# Automatically run a movie with Windows Media Player... full screen

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-media-player

I'm one step away from having this run the way I want.  I'm trying to setup an 'idiot proof' presentation for a lobby area.

I've got a computer running Windows 7 Pro, 64bit, and nothing else.  I've loaded a presentation on the computer, it's actually a .mov file... and have managed to work out the proper switches to launch WMP and having it automatically run a movie in /fullscreen mode.  However, when I automate the process, the /fullscreen option always drops out.

If I create a .bat file with the proper command line to run WMP and the movie in fullscreen mode it works great, when I run the .bat file manually.  However, when I place the commands or .bat file in the Startup menu, Run area of the Registry, or create a task in the Task Scheduler... the same thing happens.  WMP launches, the desired movie runs, then after briefly showing in fullscreen mode for a split second, it drops out into what is essentially maximized mode where the task bar is displayed.

What appears to be happening is that whenever I try to launch the command or script automatically, when the command/script completes, it won't leave WMP as the application in front.  I know WMP isn't the primary app at the time because when I hit the key sequence to enter fullscreen mode it doesn't take.  I have to click on the movie, or WMP down on the taskbar to bring WMP to the 'front' then ALT-Enter will kick in the /fullscreen mode.

Any idea how to automate the process, and have the /fullscreen mode stick?

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is because windows is still loading its components, which trigger an event. This is always a reason to drop any application out of full screen, to get the attention to the viewer. The only way you can combat this is by using the task scheduler, create the task, and set it delayed to ensure that everything has run on startup prior to the movie launching.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check if there are any WMP plug-ins loaded. Especially plug-ins of the `Now Playing` type are known to interfere with certain playback functionality.

This also may be caused by a program running in the background, so trying in [Clean Boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135) mode would be another useful step.

Answer (score 0):

First, I apply this below tips http://forum.dead-code.org/index.php?topic=3929.msg29389#msg29389

```
Simply modify this registry entry to this:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{ed1d0fdf-4414-470a-a56d-cfb68623fc58}\LocalServer32]

Modify the Default string value to this "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" /Play /Fullscreen

By the way, this only works for Windows 7 32-bit.
For it to work on Windows 7 64-bit, you need this key:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{ed1d0fdf-4414-470a-a56d-cfb68623fc58}\LocalServer32]

By the way, this works only for the movie formats that Windows Media Player supports by default.
```

But, I found popup message "Error Editing Value"

Then, I apply this below tips very carefully https://www.howtogeek.com/262464/how-to-gain-full-permissions-to-edit-protected-registry-keys/

The same as this tips [Why can't I change Window 10 registry key?](https://superuser.com/questions/986888/why-cant-i-change-window-10-registry-key)

They are worked perfectly, dude! :)