# Why can't I change Window 10 registry key?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

I want to change a Windows 7 Registry key in

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
>   -  Hidden

I ran regedit as administrator. But when I was trying to modify that key, it doesn't allow me to change and reports error as

> Cannot edit: error writing the value's new contents

So why can't I change the registry key even in administrator mode? How to solve this problem in Windows 10?

Comment: What permissions do you have in the registry key ? Value that you are trying to add, is it a REG_DWORD ?

Answer (score 19):

Interesting. I'm on Windows 10 Pro x64 and I can edit the value.

Right click on **Advanced** and choose "Permissions".

[image]

Click your user name and make sure you have **full permissions**:

[image]

If you don't, try allowing yourself full control (if the boxes are available).

If they're greyed out like in my screenshot, but you don't have full access, you can try to take ownership of the object by clicking `Advanced`

[image]

Then next to Owner click `Change`:

[image]

Type your username into the box and then press `Check Names`. Press `Okay`, then before you press `Okay` again make sure the following is selected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I still have this problem, I did everything but I can't.

Comment: What do you mean did everything? Did you have full control? If not could you give yourself full control? Did you add yourself as owner? Do you get any different error message after setting yourself as an owner?

Comment: I did everything you told me, I added myself as owner and I still get the same message

Comment: [Go here](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/take-full-permissions-control-edit-protected-registry-keys/) and continue from Step 4 and see if that works (you already did step 1-3).

Comment: You may also need to take ownership.

Comment: I suggested he take ownership in my answer.

Comment: @MiguelHernandez - Provide us more information.  Provided us screenshots of the permissions you currently have set on the key.  This is the correct answer, I assume, after you did this you restarted?

Comment: This didn't work for me either.

Comment: If you're confused what he means when he says he did everything and it didn't work: try installing Forti anti-virus, then try to take control, grant yourself full control, and change the `Start` option of `FA_Scheduler` from 3 (auto-start) to 2 (manual start). You'll notice that taking ownership, and giving yourself full control has no effect.

Comment: @IanBoyd This is it. Thanks. To disable Forticlient I followed steps from https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/497efbc9-df48-4a0e-8174-b4fc1bc543ab/unable-to-stop-a-software-from-autostarting?forum=w8itprogeneral.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in with a Microsoft account (usually this happens when you have a local user, then you try to log in into the Windows Store).

You can [add your Microsoft account](http://www.howtogeek.com/262464/how-to-gain-full-permissions-to-edit-protected-registry-keys/) into the users group by right click the registry you want to change, then *permissions*, and click in the *advanced* option.

Next to the listed owner you can add your Microsoft account (click on *change* and then use your e-mail), so this account can take ownership of any file.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people post. A part of this is including the answer in your post, [instead of simply providing a link to another page that might answer the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). Please edit your answer to include the actual solution to the posted question.

Comment: If the users account was not in the user group nothing would work.  The well documented answer is correct

Answer (score -1):

Search for Regedit under C:\windows  Once you find it, right click on it and run as administrator.  Enter credentials for administrator if needed...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).